# Firestore: Get Document ID from a specified field value found within the collection

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have a collection "users" which houses multiple documents.

I am trying to retrieve the ID of a document given a field value within each document (ie. "email")

Note, that the signin is not necessarily the user I am trying to get the ID for!

```
firebaseConfig.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value)
              .then(id => {
                if (id) {
                  const data = {
                    planid: 'WEB',
                  }
                  firebaseConfig
                    .firestore()
                    .collection('user')
                    .where("email", "==", "email@email.com")
                    .set(data, { merge: true })
                    .then(() => {
                      console.log("Success")
                    });
                }
              }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
              });
```

I get the console error of:

```
TypeError: _config__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.default.firestore(...).collection(...).where(...).set is not a function
```

I know I can update the value of that field via the below. But in my case the ID is unknown as I want to look that up via the email address stored.

```
firebaseConfig.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value)
              .then(id => {
                if (id) {
                  const data = {
                    planid: 'WEB',
                  }
                  firebaseConfig
                    .firestore()
                    .collection('user')
                    .doc("hcyfmskCVfbj77TwbXFLnJ20kH52")
                    .set(data, { merge: true })
                    .then(() => {
                      console.log("Success")
                    });
                }
              }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
              });
```

Can anyone offer any assistance?